# Flutter Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo Main Activity

Tags: java, android, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-activity

I'm using vs code (to code) and android studio (to get virtual device).
I just merged and pulled the project I'm working on this morning, and first, have a very long time to wait to build my project. So i stopped all, uninstalled my app from my virtual device, then cleaned and run by "flutter run". Now I have these errors:

```
Using hardware rendering with device AOSP on IA Emulator. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              6,0s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(11190): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11190): Process: com.example.coming_soon, PID: 11190
E/AndroidRuntime(11190): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.coming_soon/com.example.coming_soon.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.coming_soon.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.coming_soon-g9Xk6gs-AdO4Khd-H_dR3g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.coming_soon-g9Xk6gs-AdO4Khd-H_dR3g==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.coming_soon-g9Xk6gs-AdO4Khd-H_dR3g==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.coming_soon.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.coming_soon-g9Xk6gs-AdO4Khd-H_dR3g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.coming_soon-g9Xk6gs-AdO4Khd-H_dR3g==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.coming_soon-g9Xk6gs-AdO4Khd-H_dR3g==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
E/AndroidRuntime(11190):        ... 11 more
```

Here is my flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19043.1348], locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at C:\Users\Johanne\Development\sdks\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (5 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Johanne\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.62.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Johanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.28.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5556 • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 95.0.4638.69
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 95.0.1020.44

• No issues found!
```

Here is my android.manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.coming_soon">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />   
<application
        android:label="coming_soon"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I already searched and found similar issues, but I wasn't able to solve my problem.
I tried to create a MainActivity.java file, but got new errors, so I deleted it.
Did I miss something?

Comment: did you find solution? if you know please tell me i am facing this error @Joh

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to fix the name of the package in MainActivity.kt for some reason the last part was doubled.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution was to simply run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` in the project directory.

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps someone, for me the fix was to go into the MainActivity.kt file under the Android folder and to fix the package import line so that it was using the correct app id name i.e. com.company.app.